# moveit_servo won't move arm in gazebo, only oscillates

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, robotis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to use moveit_servo with a 4-DOF robot arm in gazebo to control it in real time using twist commands, just like in [this tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/realtime_servo/realtime_servo_tutorial.html).
However, as soon as I launch spacenav_cpp.launch, the arm instantly goes back to it's initial pose (if it was moved prior the launching spacenav) and oscillates (shakes) in place. If I send it a twist command, it will keep shaking, but in the direction specified in the command.

Although it is a 4-DOF arm, I am using a custom IKFast solver which works without any problems with the motion planner so I don't see why it couldn't work with moveit_servo as well.

#### How to replicate the bug

1. I have put all of the necessary files in this repo which you can clone: https://github.com/JeremieBourque1/open_manipulator
2. Start MoveIt along with the gazebo simulation `roslaunch open_manipulator_moveit_config demo_gazebo.launch`
3. Switch to the joint_group_position_controller, which is used for moveit_servo instead of the arm_controller wich is used by the motion planner. `rosservice call /controller_manager/switch_controller "start_controllers: ['joint_group_position_controller'] stop_controllers: ['arm_controller'] strictness: 0 start_asap: false timeout: 0.0"`
4. Launch the servo server. If you look closely in gazebo you should se the robot shaking `roslaunch open_manipulator_moveit_config spacenav_cpp.launch`
5. Publish a twist command. You should see the arm shaking in the direction specified in the twist command.
   `rostopic pub -r 100 -s /servo_server/delta_twist_cmds geometry_msgs/TwistStamped "header: auto twist: linear: x: 0.0 y: 0.01 z: -0.01 angular: x: 0.0 y: 0.0 z: 0.0"`

#### Additional information

- The two controller are specified in https://github.com/JeremieBourque1/open_manipulator/blob/master/open_manipulator_moveit_config/config/ros_controllers.yaml
- The spacenav configuration file is located here: https://github.com/JeremieBourque1/open_manipulator/blob/master/open_manipulator_moveit_config/config/open_manipulator_simulated_config.yaml

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374639/moveit_servo-won%27t-move-arm-in-gazebo,-only-oscillates/) by [JeremieBourque](https://answers.ros.org/users/72248/jeremiebourque/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2021-03-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PRA008](https://answers.ros.org/users/108380/pra008/) on 2022-06-21**:
Hello, I'm a newbie who is learning to use [realtime arm servoing](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/realtime_servo/realtime_servo_tutorial.html) too. I'm going to use it with the 6-DOF robot, but as I'm very new, I don't really understand what it teaches. I'd like to know what code I need to build or improve to be able to connect between can my robot_moveit_config with moveit_servo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed the issue. The problem was that the joint_state_controller was not spawned. The fix was to add this line to ros_controllers.launch

```
<node name="joint_state_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" args="spawn joint_state_controller" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [JeremieBourque](https://answers.ros.org/users/72248/jeremiebourque/) with karma: 95 on 2021-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0